# StorageFile WriteAsync operation is too slow on large files (WinRT)

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-async

I've found a strange behaviour of a StorageFile WriteAsync operation. When I create large file (approx 4gb)  and then try to write at the end of this file Write Async operation takes very long time. Looks like it fills the gap between begin and write positions. Anyway Process Manager shows high disk usage. Is it WinRT problem or am I doing something wrong? How to fix it?

```
    const long FILE_SIZE = 4294967296;
    var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("1.iso", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        stream.Size = FILE_SIZE; // size 4 Gb

        var buffer = new byte[1]; // create one byte buffer
        buffer[0] = 0xFF;

        stream.Seek(FILE_SIZE - 10); // seek almost at the and position
        await stream.WriteAsync(buffer.AsBuffer()).AsTask(); // write operation takes a lot of time

        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Dude, you're creating a 4GB file!

Comment: You are right :) Is there any way to use Sparse Files in WinRT?

Comment: No idea. Have you tried to google it on bing?

Comment: They are silent, it seems there is no support sparse files in WinRT :(